# Votes not being counted in django poll

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm working through the polls tutorial and I want to be able to have multiple questions on the same page and only press the vote button once. Right now, I don't get any errors but it is not counting the votes. I tried to write unittests to trace the error but am not sure how to replicate an html form either. In the future, I would also like other types of questions (like free text) mixed in and am not sure if I should create another app for the other question type or modify the Question and Choice in models.py. I saw some other examples but people warned against hardcoding questions/choices in the html but my form should end up remaining pretty static.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.db.models import F
from .models import Question, Choice


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'question_list': question_list}

    template_name = "polls/index.html"
    context_object_name = "question_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.all()


def index(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'question_list': question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


# class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
#     model = Question
#     template_name = "polls/detail.html"


# class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
#     model = Question
#     template_name = "polls/results.html"


def results(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'question_list': question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', context)


@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def vote(request):
    questions = get_list_or_404(Question)

    for x in questions:
        # Get list of ids from list of radio buttons
        # selected_choices_pks = request.POST[x.question_text]
        # selected_choice_pks = request.GET.getlist(questions.category_name)
        selected_choice = x.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST[x.question_text])

        # Filter choices objects using the ids
        # selected_choices = Choice.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_choices_pks)

        # Increment all the filtered choices votes by 1 using the F() expression
        # selected_choices.update(votes=F('votes') + 1)
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("polls:results"))
```

index.html

```
{% if question_list %}
    <form action="{% url 'polls:results' %}" method="post">
    {% for caty in question_list %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ caty }} <br />
        <fieldset>
        {% for choice in caty.choice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="{{ caty }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
            <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice }}</label><br />
        {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No Categories available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

results.html

```
<h1> Thanks for voting!</h1>
<ul>
{% if question_list %}
    {% for question in question_list %}
        <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Vote again?</a>
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

import datetime

from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.utils import timezone
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from .models import Question, Choice


class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is in the future.
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_can_increment_votes(self):
        """
        test that we can select a choice and have the vote count increment by 1
        """
        # q = Question.objects.all()
        # q.choice_set.all()

        client = Client()

        # Perform a vote on the poll by mocking a POST request.
        response = client.post('/polls/1/vote/', {'choice': '1', }, follow=True)

        # In the vote view we redirect the user, so check the
        # response status code is 302.
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        # Get the choice and check there is now one vote.
        choice = Choice.objects.get(pk=1)
        self.assertEqual(choice.votes, 1)
```